# Sampling Every n-th value from different sized arrays Python

Tags: python, arrays, slice

In my code, I am trying to write a way to be able to sample every n-th number from different sized arrays. Say I have:

```
x = np.linspace(0,1,41)
```

and I want to sample 6 evenly spaced out numbers from the array. I know I can write it like this:

```
xa = x[0::8]
```

to get 6 numbers throughout the array, but what if the size of the array changes, but I still want 6 evenly spaced numbers from that array? Like what if the x array now looks like:

```
x = np.linspace(0,1,26)
```

I'm not sure how to write the code to be able to extract the values for any possible sized array.

Comment: You can inquire the length of the array and space from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the step size as `len(x)//some value`

```
x=np.linspace(0,1,41)
xa=x[0::len(x)//5]

>>>xa
>>>array([0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. ])
```